# Can an inhomogeneous magnetic field be built to slow down and catch a neutron?

Tags: neutrons

Neutrons have a measureable magnetic dipole momentum from their intrinsic spin. Is it possible to slow down and catch the neutron by imposing a force by an inhomogeneous magnetic field. I think the force the neutron experiences in a magnetic field is
\begin{align}
\bar{F} = \bar{\nabla}(\bar{m}\cdot\bar{B}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the first 3D magnetic neutron trap was build at NIST in 2000. See [this popular article](http://www.nist.gov/public_affairs/releases/n00-01.cfm) for an overview, or if you can get past the paywall [this article in Nature](https://doi.org/10.1038/47444) or I think [this paper on the Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-ex/0001003) is the same publication.

It's a standard magnetic trap, after all a magnetic dipole is a magnetic dipole is a magnetic dipole. However because the neutron magnetic moment is small the trap depth was only a millikelvin or so. It took considerable effort to get neutrons cold enough to be trapped.

Comment: I find that to be very depressing to know. Neutrons are very bad for fusion reactions. I wish there was a way to harness their wasteful kinetic energy. I was wondering if a carbon nanotube with a AC bulk electron transport current could somehow induce an electromagnetic field that slows the neutron by wrenching on its spin.